# Stored Procedure Efficiency - Null Input Parameters and Where clauses

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, performance

I like to minimize the number of stored procedures I have by having a bunch of input parameters all defaulting to NULL and then those same parameters included in the WHERE with a test for Equality or NULL.

How inefficient is this in relation to query performance - verses writing stored procedure for 1 specific tasks? e.g. Select by UserId only, select by Username/Password, select by FirstName/LastName...

Example:

```
CREATE PROC dbo.up_Select_User

  @UserId int = NULL
, @Username varchar(255) = NULL
, @Password varchar(255) = NULL
, @FirstName varchar(50) = NULL
, @LastName varchar(50) = NULL
, @IsActive bit = NULL


SELECT UserId, Username, FirstName, LastName, EmailAddress
FROM dbo.[User]
WHERE (UserId = @UserId OR @UserId IS NULL)
AND (Username = @Username OR @Username IS NULL)
AND (Password = @Password OR @Password IS NULL)
AND (FirstName = @FirstName OR @FirstName IS NULL)
AND (LastName = @LastName OR @LastName IS NULL)
AND (IsActive = @IsActive OR @IsActive IS NULL)
```

Some additional info - may not be relevant... I am using entity framework 4 to map to stored procedures using a mix of normal entities and complex types depending on the query results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is inefficient because it uses OR and the optimiser will default to a scan .

If you have a few 1000 rows, it'll be OK though.

*Sometimes*, this pattern works better because the ISNULL can become trivial

```
SELECT UserId, Username, FirstName, LastName, EmailAddress
FROM dbo.[User]
WHERE
    UserId = ISNULL(@UserId, UserId) AND
    Username = ISNULL(@Username , Username) AND 
    Password = ISNULL(@Password , Password ) ...
```

Comment: OK cool - so I can get away with it for low traffic transactions with small record sets - not efficient but simplifies my model. But when I need high end performance I should be much more specific about my parameters in an effort to avoid OR clauses as much as possible. I guess I suspected as much or I wouldn't have asked the question but I didn't want to make extra work only to find out there was no advantage and that both are as efficient. Thanks gbn :-)

Comment: @Rob: yep, for larger tables you'd write more specfiic queries. If you have a small dataset then you can keep it simple. Optimise what you need to of course... In this case I assume your user table isn't tracking everyone on the planet...

Comment: thanks mate - actually the user proc is a furphy - I rarely put real data/code in these posts ;-)

Answer (score 1):

we use this way to filter

```
AND (CASE @UserId WHEN NULL THEN @UserId ELSE UserId END) = @UserId
```

We don't have performance problems with large data on SqlServer with the solution.
Some of the application views (like report overviews pages) have more than 20 filter settings and it works good with the `CASE WHEN` construct.

Edit:
These SET options have to be set

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
```

Comment: `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF` is deprecated. What do the plans look like? I would have thought this would lead to a scan?

Answer (score 0):

@gbn:
Careful, the Version with ISNULL is not exactly the same. 
E.g.
if parameter @FirstName is NULL

```
... AND (FirstName = @FirstName OR @FirstName IS NULL)
```

does not take care of FirstName values; result includes records where FirstName is NULL

while

```
... AND FirstName = ISNULL(@FirstName, FirstName)
```

result does NOT include records where FirstName is NULL

Comment: You might need to elaborate because I don't really see your point and also is the "username" in the second example supposed to be username or firstname?

Comment: Sorry for the typo, edited. Unchanged my observation that the query with ISNULL() would not deliver records from DB where FirstName is null. I used FirstName in my example, because with UserName you hardly will encounter it. Congrats if your data is that tidy that you do not encounter it at all.